# How to return 404 from Apache2 CGI program

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

I'm using mod_rewrite to redirect all incoming requests to a CGI application.  I now need to have the application return a 404 if the requested file isn't found.  How can I go about this from my program?  The first line sent is the content-type while it's the line before that that usually indicates the status (200/404/500, etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `Status` HTTP header. An example in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Status: 404 Not Found\r\n";
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

print "<h1>404 File not found!</h1>";
```

When using Perl (and other languages) however, excellent modules like [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) and [CGI::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Simple) exist.

Comment: Dang, is it really that easy?  The CGI tutorial I was following just had me sending the Content-Type line, I had assumed that the Status line was being sent by Apache.

I will give this a try tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Alright, that did the trick.

Comment: It worked but where was that documented?

Comment: @sivann It's part of the CGI specification. See section 6.3.3 in RFC 3875: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3875#section-6.3.3

Answer (score 0):

If you use perl CGI module:

```
use CGI ":standard";

print header(-status => 404);
```